# Matcher. How to get index of found group?

Tags: java, regex

I have sentence and I want to calculate words, semiPunctuation and endPunctuation in it.

Command "m.group()" will show String result. But how to know which group is found?
I can use method with "group null", but it is sounds not good.

```
String input = "Some text! Some example text."
int wordCount=0;
int semiPunctuation=0;
int endPunctuation=0;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "([\\w]+) | ([,;:\\-\"\']) | ([!\\?\\.]+)" );
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {

//  need more correct method
if(m.group(1)!=null) wordCount++;
if(m.group(2)!=null) semiPunctuation++;
if(m.group(3)!=null) endPunctuation++;

}
```

Comment: Why not have three matchers and three loops?

Comment: You can use separate patterns and problem is solved. :)

Comment: Because, calculating words, semiPunctuation and endPunctuation only first task. Second task add founded item to sorted Collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) to capture the expressions

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(?<words>\\w+)|(?<semi>[,;:\\-\"'])|(?<end>[!?.])" );
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group("words") != null) {
        wordCount++;
    } 
  ...
}
```

Comment: In the beginning "ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();" and in the loop something like this: "res.add(m.group());" And this ArrayList is sorted. That's why I can not use 3 separate loops.